# Deleting SQL entry if current date has passed a user entered date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that allows users to enter date ranges for their property availability (in the future). These entries are stored in a MySQL database along with the date in m/d/y format. I am trying to make it so that when the current day supersedes the end date of availability of the property, the entry is removed. The problem I am having is that when a user enters a date in the new year such as 6/27/2014, the entry is immediately removed - even though it is in the future. If I enter 12/28/2013 the entry is maintained. If anyone can figure out what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

This is the relevant code:

```
    $current_date = date("m/d/Y");
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `{$this->tradingpost_tbl}` WHERE end_date < '{$current_date}'");
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `{$this->seekingpost_tbl}` WHERE end_date < '{$current_date}'");
```

end_date is the user entered date in the form

Comment: `6/27/2014` is NOT a valid mysql date string anyways. If you're doing date math/comparisons in mysql, you should be using the native format: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing that you are storing your `end_date` field as a varchar and therefore when you are comparing it to some other "date", you are actually comparing it to a another string. therefore, when you try to compare "10/10/2013" to 5/10/2014 it should remove it as 5 is smaller than 10..

what you need to do is save the date in the correct field, like a "date","datetime" or a "timestamp" field.